# django: registering unzipped files on the local disk

Tags: django, django-forms, django-file-upload, django-storage

[I apologize in advance for the length of this question.]

I'm using Django 1.2.3-3+squeeze1 on Debian squeeze.

I am writing an application which uploads zip files to disk in a
temporary location, unzips them, and then saves the results to a
permanent location. The unzipped files are registered in the database as a class called
`FileUpload` after they are unzipped. The uploaded zipped files also correspond to a class,
but I'll ignore that for the purposes of this question. `FileUpload` looks like this.

```
class FileUpload(models.Model):
    folder = models.ForeignKey(FolderUpload, null=True, blank=True, related_name='parentfolder')
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(), blank=True, editable=False)
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to=file_upload_path)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200)

    def save(self):
        if not self.id:
            if self.folder == None:
                pass
            else:
                self.path = self.folder.path
        super(FileUpload, self).save()
```

I'm also using a form defined by

```
from django.forms import ChoiceField, Form, ModelForm

class FileUploadForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FileUpload
```

The function that takes the unzipped files on the disk. registers them
with the database, and moves them to the correct place is called
`addFile`. I was previously using this:

```
def addFile(name, filename, description, content, folder_id=None):
    #f = open(filename, 'r')
    #content = f.read()
    from forms import FileUploadForm
    from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
    if folder_id == None:
        data = {'name':name, 'description':description}
    else:
        data = {'name':name, 'description':description, 'folder':str(folder_id)}
    file_data = {'upload': SimpleUploadedFile(filename, content)}
    ff = FileUploadForm(data, file_data)
    try:
        zf = ff.save(commit=False)
        zf.save()
    except:
        raise RuntimeError, "Form error is %s."%(ff.errors)
    return zf
```

This worked, but the problem was that it dumped the entire file into
memory. With large files, and especially given Python isn't known for
it's memory economy, this consumed huge amounts of memory. So I
switched to this:

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import UploadedFile

class UnzippedFile(UploadedFile):

    def __init__(self, file, filepath, content_type='text/plain', charset=None):
        import os
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.name = os.path.basename(filepath)
        self.size = os.path.getsize(filepath)
        self.content_type = content_type
        self.charset = charset
        super(UnzippedFile, self).__init__(file, self.name, content_type, self.size, charset)

    def temporary_file_path(self):
        """
        Returns the full path of this file.
        """
        return self.filepath

def addFile(filepath, description, file, folder_id=None):
    import os, sys
    from forms import FileUploadForm
    from django.core.files.uploadedfile import UploadedFile
    name = os.path.basename(filepath)
    if folder_id == None:
        data = {'name':name, 'description':description}
    else:
        data = {'name':name, 'description':description, 'folder':str(folder_id)}
    file_data = {'upload': UnzippedFile(file, filepath)}
    ff = FileUploadForm(data, file_data)
    try:
        zf = ff.save(commit=False)
        zf.save()
    except:
        raise
    return zf
```

I was forced to subclass `UploadedFile`, since none of the derived
classes that were already there (in
`django/core/files/uploadedfile.py`) seemed to do what I wanted.

The `temporary_file_path` function is there because the [Django File Uploads docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/file-uploads/) say

> UploadedFile.temporary_file_path()
>
> Only files uploaded onto disk will have this method; it returns the
>   full path to the temporary uploaded file.

It seems the `FileSystemStorage` class looks for this attribute in
`_save` function as described later.

If `n` is the relative path of the file in the zip archive, then the
usage is

```
name = os.path.normpath(os.path.basename(n)) # name of file
pathname = os.path.join(dirname, n) # full file path
description = "from zip file '" + zipfilename + "'" # `zipfilename` is the name of the zip file
fname = open(pathname) # file handle
f = addFile(pathname, description, fname)
```

This works, but I traced through the code, and found that the code was
using streaming, when clearly the optimal thing to do in this case
would be to just copy the file from the temporary location to the
permanent location. The code in question is in
`django/core/files/storage.py`, in the `_save` function of the
`FileSystemStorage` class. In `_save`, `name` is the relative path of
the destination, and `content` is a `File` object.

```
def _save(self, name, content):
    full_path = self.path(name)
     directory = os.path.dirname(full_path)
     [...]
    while True:
            try:
                # This file has a file path that we can move.
                if hasattr(content, 'temporary_file_path'):
                    file_move_safe(content.temporary_file_path(), full_path)
                    content.close()

                # This is a normal uploadedfile that we can stream.
                else:
                    # This fun binary flag incantation makes os.open throw an
                    # OSError if the file already exists before we open it.
                    fd = os.open(full_path, os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL | getattr(os, 'O_BINARY', 0))
                    try:
                        locks.lock(fd, locks.LOCK_EX)
                        for chunk in content.chunks():
                            os.write(fd, chunk)
                    finally:
                        locks.unlock(fd)
                        os.close(fd)
            except OSError, e:
                if e.errno == errno.EEXIST:
                    # Ooops, the file exists. We need a new file name.
                    name = self.get_available_name(name)
                    full_path = self.path(name)
                else:
                    raise
            else:
                # OK, the file save worked. Break out of the loop.
                break
```

The `_save` function is looking for the attribute
`temporary_file_path`. I believe this code is intended to be triggered
by the `temporary_file_path` function mentioned earlier in
`django/core/files/uploadedfile.py`. However, the class that is
actually passed (corresponding to the `content` argument) is `<class
'django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile'>`, and here is what the
attribute dict (`content.__dict__`) for this object looks like:

```
{'_committed': False, 'name': u'foo', 'instance': <FileUpload: foo>,
'_file': <UnzippedFile: foo (text/plain)>, 'storage':<django.core.files.storage.DefaultStorage object at 0x9a70ccc>,
'field': <django.db.models.fields.files.FileField object at0x9ce9b4c>, 'mode': None}
```

The `temporary_file_path` is attached to the
`UnzippedFile` class, which is inside the `_file` data member. So
`content._file` has a `temporary_file_path` attribute, not `content`
itself.

This is what a regular file upload looks like. As you can see, it is similar.

```
[Fri Jun 17 08:05:33 2011] [error] type of content is <class 'django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile'>
[Fri Jun 17 08:05:33 2011] [error] {'_committed': False, 'name': u'behavior.py',
                                    'instance': <FileUpload: b>, '_file': <TemporaryUploadedFile: behavior.py (text/x-python)>,
                                    'storage': <django.core.files.storage.DefaultStorage object at 0xb8d7fd8c>,
                                    'field': <django.db.models.fields.files.FileField object at 0xb8eb584c>, 'mode': None}
```

It is difficult for me to follow in any detail how the code gets from
the `FileUploadForm` `save` to the `Storage` object. The Django form
code in particular is quite obscure.

Anyway, my question, after all this setup is, how/when is the first
option below, with `file_move_safe` supposed to be activated? I'm
seeing a mismatch here. Is this a bug? Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 0):

```
if hasattr(content, 'temporary_file_path')
```

The above will never equal true with this conditional since you state that content does not have a temporary_file_path identifier. However since content._file does you can use the following to get the functionality you are looking for

```
if hasattr(content, '_file'):
   if hasattr(content._file,'temporary_file_path'):
```

Comment: Yes, I could modify the Storage class to do this, but I'm working on the assumption that the class is meant to work out of the box, so basically, I'd like to know what the Django devs had in mind. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Sorry i did not notice that code was taken directly from one of django's core files.

Comment: Ill have to take a look at this more when im not on my mobile.